# Setting build path has encountered a p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m - A resource exists with a different case

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java project with build path related to folder that were deleted. Now I want to edit references but while saving I got following error -

> Setting build path has encountered a problem - A resource exists with a different case
>   and changes rejected.

What's wrong?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888075/eclipse-error-setting-build-path-has-encountered-error

Comment: I read it. but file option hidden is unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Close the project, re-open and try again

if this doesn't work:

- Close eclipse, re-open and try again

if this doesn't work:

- Close project, manually edit .classpath file, re-open project

Answer (score 2):

Most probably it is due to the deleted resource that is still being referenced from your build path. Make sure the the resource exists in your physical disk.

If possible can you add additional log messages.